Finite index Lie subgroup in Lie correspondence
I am working with Lie groups and more specifically at finite index Lie subgroups. I was wondering how the fact that the index of the subgroup is finite would translate under the Lie group - Lie algebra correspondence.
I came up with the following reasoning. Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a finite index normal Lie subgroup of $G$. Write $k := [G:H]$. Denote by $\mathfrak g$ and $\mathfrak h$ the Lie algebras corresponding to $G$ and $H$ respectively. We know that $\mathfrak h$ can be seen as a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$ by
$$ \mathfrak h = \{ x\in \mathfrak g\ |\ \exp(tx) \in H\ \forall t\in\mathbb{R\}}.$$
Now because $G/H$ is a group of order $k$, we have for each $x\in \mathfrak g$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$ that
$$ \exp(tx) = \exp(\frac{t}{k}x)^k$$
and hence $\exp(tx)\in H$ because $\exp(\frac{t}{k}x)\in G$. This shows that $\mathfrak h = \mathfrak g$.
Is this reasoning correct? I did not find any sources that mention this result, even though it seems to be rather elemental.
Kind regards
Lukas

Hint: A Lie group and its finite index subgroup will have the same identity component.

Hi @MoisheKohan, thank you for your comment. I do not know what you mean. Is your comment an argument against my reasoning, or another way of corroborating that this is correct?

It is a different argument. Your reasoning is correct provided you know how to justify this interpretation of the Lie algebra of $H$ in terms of the exponential map of $G$.
